# How do I rotate an object to another object's up/normal/facing vectors

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, three.js

If I have a custom plane geometry like so:

```
planeGeometry.vertices[0] = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0);
planeGeometry.vertices[1] = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 0);
planeGeometry.vertices[2] = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
planeGeometry.vertices[3] = new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0);

// faceUVs, mesh etc omitted

var right = planeGeometry.vertices[0].clone().sub(planeGeometry.vertices[1]);
var up = planeGeometry.vertices[1].clone().sub(planeGeometry.vertices[3]);

var up = up.normalize();
var normal = up.clone().cross(right).normalize();
```

How can I rotate another Object3D (CSS3DObject in my case) to have this facing normal and up vector? Can I create a quaternion or rotation matrix to do this?

Comment: The usual way is to set `cssObject.quaternion = mesh.quaternion`.

Comment: But if I create custom located vertices like this, or displace certain vertices at runtime, will that mesh's quaternion follow or is there a way to update it?

Comment: No, the quaternion wil not "follow" vertices changes.